# Can i use the token created by OpenProcessToken function in ImpersonateLoggedOnUser function

Tags: windows

Can i use the token created by `OpenProcessToken()`function in `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` function

```
irc=OpenProcessToken(
                       GetCurrentProcess(),
                        TOKEN_IMPERSONATE,
                       &tokenForUser_INTERACTIVE ); 

                if(irc==0)
                    {
                        dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
                            printf("open processtoken has failed  ");
                            sprintf(ec,"%d",dwErrorCode);


                    }
                     else
                    {
                        printf ("openProcess successs ");
                    }

and now i am trying to use "tokenForUser_INTERACTIVE" in 

irc = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(tokenForUser_INTERACTIVE);
```

and the return value is `0`.. can any one tell me i am doing wrong or will have to change some argument. (Thanks in advance)

Comment: Hard to say without more context.  What is the error code?  But if you're just trying to impersonate your own process token, you can use ImpersonateSelf().  You don't need OpenProcessToken().

Comment: The error is probably denied access. In this case a primary token handle needs `TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE` access, not `TOKEN_IMPERSONATE` access. This allows duplicating it to an impersonation token.

Comment: I also tried this one but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

You have collected the token in tokenForUser_INTERACTIVE and used tokenForUser_SERVICE in the call to ImpersonateLoggedOnUser. IS that intentional ? Otherwise you need to use tokenForUser_INTERACTIVE in the call.

The token also should have  TOKEN_QUERY and TOKEN_IMPERSONATE and only   TOKEN_IMPERSONATE has been obtained there above.

Comment: jsdevloper  Thank you . sorry by Mistake i put here   tokenForUser_Service in ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()  function  but in code i am using tokenForUser_INTERACTIVE code . and still getting error